# Set Theory and Relations help.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Hi I am struggling with these questions any help would be appreciated.
I am struggling and am not sure where to start.

Let $X = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$ and let a relation $p$ be defined as $x\,p\,y \leftrightarrow x \leq y$

List all the pairs of the relation.

Is $p$ reflexive? Prove the answer.

Is $p$ transitive? Prove the answer.

Is $p$ symmetric? Prove the answer.

Comment: Do you understand what the question is asking? If not, please say what is confusing you.

Comment: This question is meant to help you understand what the concepts reflexive, symmetric and transitive mean in a concrete setting (i.e. _understand_ the definitions, rather than just being able to recite them). That means that there is little point in us telling you the answer outright. You should read the definitions and actually try a couple of things that you think _might_ be right, because once you do, it will be easier for us to give an answer we think you will understand, and you will reap a lot more benefit from reading a correct answer. Also, trial and error is important when doing math.

Comment: Start with the definitions. **Always** start with the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

p is not symmetric since (1,2) is there but (2,1) is not there.It is transitive since x<=y and y<=z implies x<=z.p is reflexive since x<=x.

Answer (score 0):

The list of pairs that can be related are all pairs of elements from $X$. They are $1p1$, $1p2$, $1p3$, $2p1$, $2p2$, $2p3$, $3p1$, ... , $3p3$.

To show that the relation p is reflexive, you must show that all elements in $X$ are in relation with themselves, i.e. $1\leqslant1$, $2\leqslant2$ and $3\leqslant3$ must be true. I hope it is clear to you that this is obviously true.

To show that p is transitive you must show that if $x\leqslant y$ and $y\leqslant z$ for $x,y,z$ in $X$ then $x\leqslant z$. For example $1\leqslant2$ and $2\leqslant3$ and $1\leqslant3$. However, You must show this for all elements in $X$. 
I think it is a good excercise for a first time to try all combinations to get a grasp of what a relation is.

To show that p is symmetric you must show that if $x\leqslant y$ then $y\leqslant x$. Hint: This relation is not symmetric. Can you find a counter-example?

Comment: Awesome, So you not include 2p3? when listing the pairs?

Comment: Yes you do. My mistake.